# Can i 'hold' POST data in ASP.NET, so i can verify with Captcha?

Tags: c#, asp.net, post

I have a complex page with maybe a dozen POST element and a file upload (non ajax ATM).
I have a form with a description, if it causes akismet to find it as spam i would like the user to be informed and either hit back on their browser to try again or to hold call POST data so the user can fill in a reCaptcha to bypass the spam marking.

How do i hold the POST data? i have no idea how to redirect the user to this captcha page and to keep all the post data. It would be preferable if it was generic and i didnt need to copy the post and get data by hand.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to create hidden form fields with all received data. This is easy to do it generically, just iterate through all $_POST elements and create a new hidden field for each one.
Obviously you must create a valid form.
Once this new page is loaded you should redirect to desired location.

Comment: I'm not sure that using a hidden field for an image will make sense. You can save the image (and everything else) on disk and put its location in session or in a cookie so you can find it later, among other options.

Comment: I think he is not asking to keep the image from page to page but data from a form.