# How do i save POST and GET data into a session and pull it up with ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, get

From what i understand session cookies are serverside and not transmitted to the user at all.
This means it is safe from tampering (from outside of the server)?

Anyways, from what i can tell POST data is stored in HttpContext.Current.Request.Form. How do i get GET data?

right now i am doing this

```
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
            foreach (var v in HttpContext.Current.Request.Form)
                HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(v, HttpContext.Current.Request[v]);
```

Other then needing to be careful when clearing my session data is this code a good idea or bad idea? I am trying to solve this problem [Can i 'hold' POST data in ASP.NET, so i can verify with Captcha?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073094/can-i-hold-post-data-in-asp-net-so-i-can-verify-with-captcha)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var v in HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString)
```

Answer (score 1):

A session **cookie** IS transmitted to the browser. That browser then resends that cookie with every request - that is how the server knows the requests belong to the same Session.

The Session **data** however is kept only on the server, nothing about that is transmitted to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can get GET data from the querystring HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString

Answer (score 0):

> *How do i get GET data?*

Hiya,

To access **GET** data you need to look inside **Request.Params**

Here's some sample code to demonstrate usage.

```
//get the param with the requested name
string paramValue = Request.Params["paramName"];
```